# NPM Login using CLI and automation token working as expected

Tags: authentication, npm, automation, token, publish

I am actually a bit confused about these automation tokens and the login using the CLI with NPM.

I'm building a publishing script for my CI pipeline. That's why I need a login that is working without a 2FA or OTP via mail. So I created an automation token on npm and used it to login like:

```
npm login --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/ --scope=@myScope --always-auth --auth.token=myToken --no-progress --yes
```

Buuuut it prompts me to login in the browser to proceed.

```
npm notice Log in on https://registry.npmjs.org/
Login at:
https://www.npmjs.com/login?next=/login/cli/efa3d25e-4d4c-4ce7-b366-811e55e29a57
Press ENTER to open in the browser...
```

I assume I'm doing something very basic wrong here, since I'm pretty new to npm.

Any ideas what I'm missing?